# DNX 4.5.1 vs DNX Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net, mono, dnx

I'm developing ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 REST api (web api). Some things is missing in DNX Core 5.0. I know that I can remove dnxcore50 to solve that problem, but main question is that with DNX 4.5.1 I will be able to run my API either in Linux, OSX ? I will be forced to use Mono? All of DNX 4.5.1 packages will work properly in mentioned systems?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if your project only targets dnx451 (now net451), it will **not** run on linux or OSX. For that you should target dnxcore or mono. The text also explains that .NET Core is not fully featured at the moment, but it is rapidly growing.

[This text](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) explains the early plans for the .NET Platform Standard. It might help you get a grasp of things to come.

Comment: Uhm, yes. This question kind of became obsolete with the release of .NET Core 1.0 and the new tooling.